# Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given - PHP

Tags: php

My code:

```
public function valRef($arr) {

        $refs = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        }

        var_dump($refs);

       //var_dump($refs) returns something like this:
       array(1) {
       [0]=>
       &int(1)

        return $refs;
}
```

This is where the function is used. I don't understand why the returned `$refs` array is different. Shouldn't it be the same as the one above?

```
var_dump($this->helperClass->valRef($ref));
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
}

        call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($q, $prep), $this->helperClass->valRef($ref)));
```

Comment: PDO makes this sort of thing trivial. `mysqli` is a much clunkier interface that causes a lot of friction. Are you committed to `mysqli` at this point?

Comment: `call_user_func_array` expects **2** parameters. The first parameter is the method name, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` and the second parameter is the array of arguments supplied to the method.

Comment: @tadman This is an old project. I just want to make it work.  I don't have the time to redo the whole thing. So I guess I'm stuck with mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';

function valRef(&$arr)
{
    $refs = array();

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    }

    var_dump($refs);
    echo '<hr>';

    return $refs;
}


$arr = array(1, 5, 7, "hello");

$refs = valRef($arr);

var_dump($refs);
echo '<hr>';


$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'testman', 'agave');

$q = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?");

$prep = "iiis";

call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($q, $prep), $refs));

mysqli_stmt_execute($q);


mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q, $c1, $c2, $c3, $c4);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($q))
{
    echo "$c1, $c2, $c3, $c4";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($q);

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

I ran this on my server, and got the following output in my web broswer:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  &int(1)
  [1]=>
  &int(5)
  [2]=>
  &int(7)
  [3]=>
  &string(5) "hello"
}
```

---

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  &int(1)
  [1]=>
  &int(5)
  [2]=>
  &int(7)
  [3]=>
  &string(5) "hello"
}
```

---

```
1, 5, 7, hello
```

Helps?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and see as it goes.

Comment: You're welcome.  ... I could really use that bounty, hint, hint... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because you are passing valRef($arr) as the parameter. since the function is not a referenced variable it cannot find a pointer to it. Once assigned to a variable, it will have a reference pointer to work with.